# Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP. AH00013: Pre-configuration failed

Tags: php, apache

How to fix this error in Termux?

> Android 9 pie
>
> u0_a197@localhost
>
> /d/d/c/f/u/e/apache2> apachectl start
>
> [Mon Feb 24 10:44:37.594174 2020] [php7:crit] [pid 27013:tid 508989617480] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
> AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
> u0_a197@localhost
> /d/d/c/f/u/e/apache2>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

disable mpm_worker and enable module mpm_prefork
ex:
edit file httpd.conf :
`LoadModule mpm_prefork_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_prefork.so`
`#LoadModule mpm_worker_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_worker.so`

Comment: In my case, there is no mpm_prefork_module reference in httpd.conf

Comment: Question is to enable mpm_event and not to run with prefork

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ubuntu/Debian systems, you can use `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` to enable or disable an apache2 module

To disable mpm_worker:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_worker
```

To enable mpm_prefork:

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

(Don't forget to restart your server)

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am using `arch linux` and I get the same error, for me the following works:

```
sudo nvim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    #LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
    LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

    LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
    AddHandler php-script .php

    Include conf/extra/php_module.conf
```

`sudo systemctl restart httpd`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server#Extensions

Answer (score 1):

Make sure mod_php is not installed.

```
sudo yum remove mod_php -y
```

It is the oldest and slowest possible configuration. It was suitable for version 2.2 and older, and requires the use of the prefork mpm.

You can check if you're server is using mod_php by looking in output of phpinfo()

[image: mod_php used]

Correct/multi-threaded configuration will show Fast CGI:

[image: FPM/FastCGI used]