# Apache2 failing when enabling php mod (Ubuntu 20.4)

Tags: php, apache2, lamp, ubuntu-20.04, php-5.3

I've install php5.3 (from ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/php53), but when installing apache2 and then enabling it through `sudo a2enmod php53` the output says to run `sudo systemctl restart apache2`, however this causes the apache2 server to stop, and it is unable to start again after that.

Below is the output from running `journalctl -xe`:

```
The job identifier is 5493.
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 apachectl[10817]: [Wed Mar 06 13:49:01.199228 2024] [:crit] [pid 10817:tid 140524561787968] Apache is running a threaded M>
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 apachectl[10817]: AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 apachectl[10814]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 apachectl[10814]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 sudo[10806]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 06 13:49:01 ip-172-31-39-129 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 5493 and the job result is failed.
```

Apache 2 Error Log:

```
[Wed Mar 06 13:48:07.632271 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10483:tid 140403607956544] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 06 13:48:07.632364 2024] [core:notice] [pid 10483:tid 140403607956544] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Mar 06 13:49:01.156933 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10483:tid 140403607956544] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

(For context I have also installed the following packages mysql-server php53 libapache2-mod-php53 php53-xml php53-mbstring, I do not have php53-mysql as it is not available)

Any ideas on why this is and how I can solve this?

Comment: The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Just added it, any obvious reasons?

Comment: It seems that the error has been truncated, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370020/apache-is-running-a-threaded-mpm-but-your-php-module-is-not-compiled-to-be-thre